# Fourth cohomology of the modular group

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, group-cohomology, modular-group

Is $H^4(PSL(2,\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z})$ known? I ask this in response to the recent calculation of the same cohomology group for $\mathrm{Co}_0$ and $\mathrm{Co}_1$.

Comment: Doesn't this follow easily from $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})\cong C_2\ast C_3$?

Comment: So what's the answer then?

Comment: @JohnBaez $H^n(C_2\ast C_3,\mathbb{Z})\cong H^n(C_2,\mathbb{Z})\oplus H^n(C_3,\mathbb{Z})$, which is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ for $n=4$.

Comment: The classifying space is the one-point union of those for $C_2$ and $C_3$, hence the homology is the direct sum (except in degree 0).

Comment: @JeremyRickard Well that's an anticlimax!

Comment: To relieve that anticlimax, there are things like $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z}_{59})$ with $H^4 = \mathbb{Z}_{(2*3*5*29)}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Jeremy Rickard's comments, the group cohomology (with coefficients a module with trivial action) of a free product of (discrete) groups is sent to direct sum (eg Proposition 1.3.16.3 in C. Löh, *[Group Cohomology & Bounded Cohomology](https://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/u/clara.loeh/topologie3_ws0910/prelim.pdf)* (pdf)), so 
$$
H^n(PSL(2,\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z}) \simeq H^n(C_2\ast C_3,\mathbb{Z})\simeq H^n(C_2,\mathbb{Z})\oplus H^n(C_3,\mathbb{Z}),
$$ 
and positive, even-degree cohomology of cyclic groups is $H^{2k}(C_n,\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}/n$ ($k\gt 0$) and $0$ in odd degree, hence $H^4(PSL(2,\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}/2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/3$.